# Any difference between the following function expressions

Tags: javascript

I have seen people use this pattern frequently:

```
(function() { })();
```

Although I have never seen anybody use:

```
void function() { }();
```

Are there any differences?

Comment: Yes, the `void` one will force the IIFE to return `undefined` if it returns something other than `undefined`. Presumably this is not useful, longer and less understandable than the first option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main diffrence is that `(function() { })();` can return value, if there is return statment. `void function() { }();` will always return undefined.

```
var f = (function() { return true; })();
var v = void function() { return true; }();


console.log(f); // Will output `true`
console.log(v); // Will output `undefined`
```

Comment: What does brakets ("( )" which is last ) need.

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates an empty function (function expression) and calls it. Since the function does not have any [`return` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9), [`undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9) is returned.

```
(function() { })(); // undefined
(function() {
  1+2+3;
  "I don't have any `return` statement";
})();               // undefined
```

The `void` operator takes an argument, evaluates it, and always returns `undefined`. In this case, the argument is a function expression. The function is evaluated and returns `undefined` (again, because it doesn't have `return`), but that returned value is ignored.

```
void function() { }(); // undefined
void "trololo";        // undefined
```

So they are ways of producing `undefined`. Instead, I recommend using

- `undefined`, for clarity. Note it isn't a literal: [it's a global variable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3). In ES3 it was alterable, and in ES5 it can be shadowed, so may be not reliable.
- `void 0`, for shortness and reliability.